# VBA formula to add new row with formula

Tags: excel, vba, button, row, formula

Can anyone help me adjust this code to fix my solution?

I have a button that adds x amount of new rows from A5 downwards. Columns A - Z.

I would like the new rows to be blank but still contain dropdowns and formula. New to VBA and struggling with this one.

I think I need to change the range and add xlPasteFormulas but unsure where and how for both. Any help hugely appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddRows()

    Dim x As Integer

    x = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")

    'Selecting range to insert new cells
    Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(x + 4, 1)).EntireRow.Insert

    'Copys current cell A6 and past in the new cells
    Cells(x + 5, 1).Copy Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(x + 4, 1))

    'if you want the cells to be blank but still have the drop down options
    Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(x + 4, 1)).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you post this yesterday?  I added a comment, you are only copying 1 cell. `Cells(x + 5, 1).Copy`

Comment: Yeah sorry. I tried increasing the range but I wasn’t sure how and it kept coming up error. How would I change this to copy A5:A26. I have a presentation on this workbook today at lunchtime.

Comment: Have a look at something/do some research,`cells` for example.   You are only copying 1 row using `Cells(x + 5, `1`).Copy ` would sort of give it away, where to start. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below. It will copy everything from the `BaseRow` and then delete constant values in that range, leaving formats, including data validations, and formulas.

```
Sub AddRows()

    Const BaseRow As Long = 11   ' modify to suit

    Dim x As String             ' InputBox returns text if 'Type' isn't specified
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long

    x = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")
    If x = "" Then Exit Sub
    R = BaseRow + CInt(x) - 1

    Rows(BaseRow).Copy          'Copy BaseRow
    'specify range to insert new cells
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(BaseRow, 1), Cells(R, 1))
    Rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    ' insert the new rows BEFORE BaseRow
    ' to insert below BaseRow use Rng.Offset(BaseRow - R)
    Set Rng = Rng.Offset(BaseRow - R - 1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
    Rng.Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    Application.CutCopyMode = False '
End Sub
```

The code now has an emergency exit: If you don't enter anything in the InputBox the procedure terminates. Note that new rows are inserted above the `BaseRow`. After the insertion all new rows and the old row are identical. You can then choose to retain the constants in either the first or the last of these rows, effectively meaning, insert new, blank rows either above or below the `BaseRow`.

Comment: This works on a new worksheet but as soon as I add headers to my table A run-error '1004' pops up saying "this won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet. I click debug and it highlights "Rng.Insert Shift:=x1Down" Any help hugely appreciated

Comment: The apparent fact that your BaseRow is in a table is a secret you have preserved well until now. You might try to add the rows below the BaseRow, if that serves your purpose, in the hope that Excel will not consider that "moving cells within a table". If that doesn't work for you, the entire question must be rephrased. Since that would be a totally different question, technically speaking, the rephrasing couldn't be done within this same thread. almost nobody would look at it here except me, and I won't allow the change. Ask a new question in that case.